# how to assign value to select tag in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have a select box. For updating I retrieve data from database. So how can I assign retrieved values to select options?

For example:

```
 $scope.options = [{ name: "Select Gender", id: 0 }, { name: "Male", id: 1 }, { name: "Female", id: 2 }];
```

These are the options. I want to assign `Male` to the select box. How can I do this?

This is the [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/YRIQ1KIagRaENZe7Jlle?p=preview) I created for reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please look at the [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/5fMgHbNJyuanpGnQ8GBC?p=preview) based on your one.

First of all, you have to do:

```
$scope.selectedOption = $scope.options[1];
```

Then [`ng-options`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) directive should look like:

```
data-ng-options="o.id as o.name for o in options track by o.id"
```